# btrfs external SSD forced read-only, will mount, some files unstable — how to recover data?

Tags: readonly

I formatted an external SSD with the btrfs filesystem and had been using it fine reading and writing to it whether I am root or the only other user. I think Pop OS did not like how the ssd was removed and there were red errors across the screen when it was shutting down. Since then the SSD drive (sda1) is read only. I think the Pop!_OS errors mentioned LVM. I don't know where the Pop shutdown error log might be so I can tell you exactly what it said. I found what looks like a boot up log, but the shutdown log would help too.

This is from the journal.log:

```bash
Feb 04 23:21:07 pop-os kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Feb 04 23:21:07 pop-os kernel: system76_acpi: loading **out-of-tree** module **taints** kernel.
Feb 04 23:21:33 pop-os kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): bdev /dev/sda1 errs: wr 1, rd 2, flush 0, **corrupt** 3, gen 0
Feb 04 23:21:38 pop-os kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 **FAILED** Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Feb 04 23:21:38 pop-os kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
Feb 04 23:21:38 pop-os kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Feb 04 23:21:38 pop-os kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 e1 2b 88 00 00 80 00
Feb 04 23:21:38 pop-os kernel: **critical** target error, dev sda, sector **14756744** op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0

Feb 04 23:21:39 pop-os kernel: **critical** target error, dev sda, sector **60338288** op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0

Feb 04 23:21:41 pop-os kernel: **critical** target error, dev sda, sector **73452720** op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0

Feb 04 23:22:04 pop-os kernel: **critical** target error, dev sda, sector **154215456** op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 64 prio class 0

Feb 04 23:22:04 pop-os kernel: **BTRFS error** (device sda1): **error reading free space cache**
Feb 04 23:22:04 pop-os kernel: BTRFS warning (device sda1): failed to load free space cache for block group 40832598016, rebuilding it now

Feb 04 23:22:05 pop-os kernel: **BTRFS warning (device sda1): chunk 13631488 missing 1 devices, max tolerance is 0 for writable mount**
Feb 04 23:22:05 pop-os kernel: **BTRFS: error (device sda1) in write_all_supers:4433: errno=-5 IO failure (errors while submitting device barriers.)**
Feb 04 23:22:05 pop-os kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1: state E): **forced readonly**
Feb 04 23:22:05 pop-os kernel: BTRFS warning (device sda1: state E): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
Feb 04 23:22:05 pop-os kernel: BTRFS: error (device sda1: state **EA**) in cleanup_transaction:1982: **errno=-5 IO failure**
```

I tried accessing the drive with a couple of other applications in case the combination of error messages could help. The Gparted dialogue window labeled, "Libparted Warning" gave the error message, "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda1: Remote I/O error". LibreWriter gave two errors:  "Error saving the document..pathtothedrive does not exist." and "Error saving the document filename:  Write Error.  The file could not be written."

And here's how it behaves in the dolphin file manager:  I can copy some files over onto the laptop internal SSD, but some files just hang it up and will not copy then a dolphin error message pops up: "(Errno: 5)". I have also seen this other error message from dolphin:  "One or more files on this device are opened in application "dolphinqhVENO.57.slave-socket"." (What does that mean?) Here's what also happened:  I would go in some directories and see NO files in it. (Usually (now) I see the files but cannot copy.) Then I go over and run `testdisk` so far as to see it has a GPT partition table and notice it is btrfs, a filesystem it does not work further on, THEN back to dolphin and I can see files back in the directory. On an image file, dolphin shows a mini thumbnail and I can see the whole image it knows about, but to pull it up in GIMP, there is either a blacked-out image or one other showed the top 5th of the image and everything below it had been blacked out. One more interesting thing – the files that did copy   I went to move those off the laptop onto a safer other external SSD. Some of those files moved over as expected AND SOME DID NOT, dolphin coming back with that same Errno: 5. Is my data still there like I think it is something like the tree structure needs to be realigned and stabilized? Then the directories will 'know' what files are in them and the files 'know' what data is in them? The SSD is fairly new and I wonder if those sectors I bolded above are really bad and unusable going forward or some 'alignment' that is just off enough at those points to trigger errors and fixing the overall structure will pull that into place also. Does something need to be synced/closed like Gparted mentioned? And unless it is the problem follows even just the files around - off of that drive?

```bash
$ sudo btrfs check /dev/sda1
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda1
UUID: (the number)
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
Error reading 80022618112, -1
failed to load free space cache for block group 40832598016
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 109238472704 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 106517876
total tree bytes: 137166848
total fs tree bytes: 3325952
total extent tree bytes: 2850816
btree space waste bytes: 23485371
file data blocks allocated: 109145407488
 referenced 109100597248
```

```bash
$ dmesg | tail
[ 3370.531377] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 3370.531640] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[ 3370.531644] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 3370.531814] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 3370.531817] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 5f 00 00 08
[ 3370.532132] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3370.532250] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[ 3370.532253] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
[ 3370.537416]  sda: sda1
[ 3370.537565] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: `the Pop error log` ... it's linux so, the log files are in `/var/log`

Comment: `Pop OS did not like how the ssd was removed` .... how was it removed? `Pop did something to the ssd drive` depends on what you did

Comment: What model is this? Some Samsung SSDs have a bug that can turn them read only.

Comment: the SSD is a PNY.

Comment: there were a lot of files and directories in /var/log. i did not see any clues when i looked around. I know I saw LVM error messages though on shutdown. If LVM changes a drive to R/O and loads a mirror of an attached SSD to make changes to that THEN transfer the changes to the actual SSD when unmounting it as expected and that unmount-as-expected step is skipped.. does it (LVM) leave the SSD in an unstable state and it reverts to R/O? How to override something LVM2 might have done to the drive?